# How to change the data format when using StackedAreaChart in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-svg-charts

I am using [react-native-svg-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts) to make `StackedAreaChart` and this is the format of data I'm using

```
 const hardCodedData = [
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
            BackLeft: 1600,
            BackRight: 1440,
            FrontLeft: 960,
            FrontRight: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 4, 1),
            BackLeft: 3840,
            BackRight: 1920,
            FrontLeft: 960,
            FrontRight: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 8, 1),
            BackLeft: 640,
            BackRight: 960,
            FrontLeft: 3640,
            FrontRight: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 3, 7),
            BackLeft: 3320,
            BackRight: 480,
            FrontLeft: 640,
            FrontRight: 400,
        },
    ]
```

The problem I'm facing is that I will not always get the values for the same `date` for all 4 entries, for example

```
 {
   month: new Date(2015, 4, 1),
   BackLeft: 3840,
   BackRight: "not available",
   FrontLeft: 960,
   FrontRight: "not available",
 },
```

I tried to put `undefined` but I've got an error.

How can I handle this type of change?

Comment: Did you tried Null?

Comment: Yes I tried that but in vain